# How to accept pointer to a function with any number of parameters, as a parameter in C and call it?

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm building a hashmap API. In that API, I have a `hashmap_new()` function that creates a new hashmap (acts like a constructor). I want the user to be able to specify be able to supply pointer to their own hash function as an argument to `hashmap_new()`.

The problem I'm facing is that this user-defined hash function can have any number of arguments and that too in any order.  For instance: some hash functions require only the data as an argument, some require data and length, while others require data, length and seed(s).

My code looks something like this:

```c
struct hashmap *hashmap_new(int capacity, uint64_t (*hash_fn)(const void *key, uint64_t len))
{
  ... // code for allocation and setting other variables
  map->hash_fn = hash_fn;

  return map;
}
```

After setting the hash function for my map, I want to call it from other parts of my code wherever required. How can I write `hashmap_new()` function that accepts a pointer to hash function that accepts any number of arguments and how can i call that function with that many number of arguments?

Comment: it sounds like you want to use function overloading in a language that does not support function overloading. Can you please show more code of what you mean. Example of creating and calling.

Comment: For me two solutions, first Macro, second force number of args (for example only one typed as void *)

Comment: Pass a pointer to a function with a signature that takes variadic arguments

Comment: @Ôrel Yeah I think I'll go with forcing one typed void * argument. Thanks!

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks for the comment! variadic arguments require ordering arguements, which is not what I want

Comment: The sane way is to force an API upon the user. Give them a pre-defined function format with all the parameters they could possibly use. If they don't need some, they can call those with NULL etc.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the comment! I thought of that as the last resort. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare your hash functions to take a single `void *` argument.  Then for each function, define a struct that contains the parameters for that hash, and inside the function convert the `void *` to a pointer to the appropriate struct type.

Later when you call the hash function, populate an instance of the appropriate struct and pass a pointer to that struct to the function.

Comment: I'm thinking of using double `void *` arguments. One for data and other for the struct that contains other parameters. I can create a `hashmap_set_hash_fn()` function that a user can use to set hash their hash function and provide it with a struct that contains paramters other than data (which is the second argument for my in-built hash function signature). That way, the populating the struct can be done only once.